# how to get category name if my category got custom slug

Tags: php

so my category got slug 'aeroplanes' and I need to get category names from it, but I can't get it with

```
$category = get_the_category($post->ID); 
echo $category[0]->cat_name;
```

cause it takes all posts from default category with category slug 'category'. How can I do that if I got category slug 'aerpolanes'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [categories with different slug](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31646/categories-with-different-slug)

Answer (score 2):

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by

The following code will work for your situation:

```
$cat = get_term_by( 'slug', 'aeroplane', 'category');
echo $cat->name;
```

Comment: Hello, it didn't help. It echoed nothing. + I got many subcategories in category that got slug aeroplane, and I need to echo those subcategory names.

Comment: @Y2ok - check the spelling in the answer by Russel Heimlich; make sure you use exactly the slug of your category ('aeroplanes'). you didn't directly ask for the child categories - please edit your question to make that clear.