# How to get child categories of a given Post

Tags: categories

how do I get names of child categories of an arbitrary Post?

For example i got category slug - 'motorbikes' and I got subcategories for it. So I need to get each posts subcategory name thats inside category with slug motorbikes.
Y2ok

Comment: Can you explain the relevance of the category slug *changing*, as opposed to the question merely being a matter of getting the child categories of a category parent?

Comment: Hello, normally category slug is 'category', but for me it's 'motorbikes', and inside category slug 'motorbikes' i got subcategories. In subcategories i Got posts, and I need to get subcategory name with 
`$cat = get_the_category($post->ID);
$category_name = $cat->name;` , but I can't cause it returns empty array.

Comment: I still don't understand. What do you mean by "*normally category slug is 'category'*"? Are you by chance talking about the **category URL base**?

Comment: Hello, yes exactly.

Comment: Umm... that's different from your comment below. So, unless my edited answer answers your question, I'm still confused about what you need.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get the child categories of a given parent category slug, use a combination of [`get_category_by_slug()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_by_slug) and [`get_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories).

The latter function will return an array of category objects matching the specified query arguments array; the former will return the ID of a category, given its slug.

So, for example:

```
<?php
$motorbike_child_cat_args = array(
    'child_of' => get_category_by_slug( 'motorbikes' )
);

$motorbike_child_cats = get_categories( $motorbike_child_cat_args );
?>
```

Then, you can do whatever you want with your array-of-category-objects. For example, to get an array of child-category names:

```
<?php
$motorbike_child_cat_names = array();
foreach ( $motorbike_child_cats as $child_cat ) {
    $motorbike_child_cat_names[] = $child_cat->name;
}
?>
```

Really, what you do with it is up to you at that point.

**EDIT**

If you need to get *child categories* of an *arbitrary post*, then you can use [`get_the_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category).

If you're *inside* the Loop, simply call `get_the_category()`; if you're *outside* the Loop, then you need to pass the Post ID to the call: `get_the_category( $id )`.

So, for example, to build an array of names of child categories (regardless of parent) of the current post:

```
<?php
$my_post_categories = get_the_category();

$my_post_child_cats = array();
foreach ( $my_post_categories as $post_cat ) {
    if ( 0 != $post_cat->category_parent ) {
        $my_post_child_cats[] = $post_cat->cat_name;
    }
}
?>
```

Or, for example, to build an array of names of 'motorbike' child categories of the current post:

```
<?php
$my_post_categories = get_the_category();

$motorbikes_child_cats = array();
foreach ( $my_post_categories as $post_cat ) {
    if ( 'motorbikes' == $post_cat->category_parent ) {
        $motorbikes_child_cats[] = $post_cat->cat_name;
    }
}
?>
```

Is that more what you're looking for?

**EDIT 2**

If you just need to get all the categories of your post:

```
<?php
$all_post_categories = get_the_category();

$my_post_cats = array();
foreach ( $my_post_categories as $post_cat ) {
    $my_post_cats[] = $post_cat->cat_name;
}
?>
```

That will give you **all** of the categories for the current Post. I have no idea how **`motorbikes`** category slug factors into this question.

Comment: Hello, thank you, but how can I get subcategory name of $post->ID , cause `$cat = get_the_category($post->ID); $category_name = $cat->name;` won't work.

Comment: So, are you trying to get the *child categories* of an *arbitrary post*, rather than the *child categories* of a *known category*, 'motorbikes'?

Comment: Hello, yes, could you help me with that?

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: Hello, yes but how can i echo it? If i do something like this - echo $motorbikes_child_cats[0]; or echo $my_post_child_cats[0]; it will just echo empty.

Comment: What do you get with `<?php var_dump( $my_post_child_cats ); ?>`? If it's empty, are you sure that your post *actually has child categories*?

Comment: Hello, it returns NULL, so it means I don't have subcategories? If so, how then I get name of category for my post, if category slug is 'motorbikes'?

Comment: Can you please explain **where on earth "*category slug is 'motorbike'*" is coming from**?

Answer (score 0):

```
$categories = wp_get_post_categories( get_the_ID(), array('fields' => 'ids') );

$arguments = array(
    'taxonomy'    => 'category',
    'childless'   => true,
    'include'     => $categories,
);

$selected_category = get_terms( $arguments );
```

Comment: Please **edit your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem? See [answer]